# Sharepoint configuration to overwrite and versioning

Tags: sharepoint, configuration

Is it possible to configure sharepoint server to handle both versioning and file overwrite at the same time?

Do you have a link for that :P

:)

Thanks

**EDIT**

background.

I saw a small demo, where , when a file is being uploaded, there is a checkbox that reads "Use versioning". If checked, a new version of the file is created. If not, the server reject the upload saying the file already exists.

I've been told that Sharepoint can be configured to overwrite an existing file.  So, in this case what I would expect is if the "versioning" checkbox is selected, a new version of the file will be created. If checkbox is not selected, the file will be replaced ( overwritten )

The problem is, I don't know if this "configuration" is possible or not.

Comment: Not sure what your question means at all... Within a document library? Exactly what behaviour are you looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I've checked this and it seems that **the configuration you described is not possible**.

The *Overwrite existing files* checkbox is only visible when **versioning is disabled** (see the screenshot below); it disappears when versioning is enabled.

[image: Versioning disabled]

---

This is what [Office documentation says about this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100929191033.aspx#2):

> If you are uploading a revised version
>   of an existing file, do one of the
>   following:
>
> - If your library is **not configured to track versions** of files, you can
>     **replace the existing file with the revised file**. In the Upload Document
>     section, select the Overwrite existing file(s)? check box.
> - If your library is **configured to track versions** of files, you can
>     **replace the existing file with the new version as part of the document
>     history**. In the Upload Document section, select the Add as a new
>     version to existing files? check box.

Comment: This is very helpful chopeen. Thank you. Do you happen to have a link on this ? :P

Comment: I found no official documentation that explicitly says that the configuration you described is not possible. However, I pasted an excerpt in my answer that confirms it implicitly.